# I am crazy with django,No module named xxx

Tags: django

I am not american.I wish i can express clear what i occur.

```
**Django wrong log:**
    ImportError at /accounts/signin/
    No module named coltrane
    Request Method: GET 
    Request URL: http://abc.com:8080/accounts/signin/ 
    Django Version: 1.4.1 
    Exception Type: ImportError 
    Exception Value: No module named coltrane 
    Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35 
    Python Executable: /usr/bin/python 
    Python Version: 2.6.6 
    Python Path: ['/home/graduate',
     '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL',
     '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
     '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info'] 
    Server time: 星期二, 23 四月 2013 11:27:33 +0800 

    Error during template rendering
    In template /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/userena/templates/userena/signin_form.html, error at line 29

    No module named coltrane
    19     </p>

    20     {% else %}

    21     <p>

    22     {{ field.label_tag }}

    23     {{ field }}

    24     </p>

    25     {% endif %}

    26     {% endfor %}

    27   </fieldset>

    28   <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Signin" %}" />

    29   <p class="forgot-password"><a href="{% url 'userena_password_reset' %}" title="{% trans 'Forgot your password?' %}">{% trans "Forgot your password?" %}</a></p>

    30   {% if next %}<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />{% endif %}

    31 </form>

    32 {% endblock %}

    33
```

But my setting file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'userena',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'guardian',
    'graduate.coltrane',
    'graduate.accounts',
)
```

my project dir:

```
[root@fuwuqi graduate]# pwd
/home/graduate/graduate
[root@fuwuqi graduate]# ls
accounts  coltrane  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  settings.py  settings.pyc  templates  urls.py  urls.pyc  wsgi.py  wsgi.pyc
[root@fuwuqi graduate]#
```

I am crazy why django tell me "No module named coltrane", i am confused.

This problem take me a long time until now.

So i just go bed,hope some one can give me a hand.

Comment: The template engine does not like line 29, the line beginning <p class="forgot-password">.

Comment: you have ``graduate.coltrane`` in installed_apps, perhaps you need to do ``from graduate import coltrane`` !!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the `PYTHONPATH`, `/home/graduate/graduate` would need to be on the path in order to make the `coltrane` package importable.

You'll need to review your project configuration or move the `coltrane` package to `/home/graduate`.

Comment: sometimes I add "export PYTHONPATH="/home/graduate/graduate/coltrane/:$PYTHONPATH"" in ~/.bash_profile,but it also not work.

Comment: You should add just `/home/graduate/graduate`. When the `import coltrane` statement is executed, all the directories defined on your `PYTHONPATH` will be traversed to check if there is a module (`~graduate/graduate/coltrane.py`) or a package (`~graduate/graduate/coltrane/__init__.py`) located in any of the directories. If you added the package directly on the `PYTHONPATH` it would expect to find `~graduate/graduate/coltrane/coltrane.py` or `~graduate/graduate/coltrante/coltrane/__init__.py`, which isn't correct.

Comment: thanks Filip! You just got me out a hole when I moved a Django project to another machine and forgot about adding the PYTHONPATH :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the **url template tag** wihtout the ''

```
 29   <p class="forgot-password"><a href="{% url 'userena_password_reset' %}"
```

This way

```
{% url userena_password_reset %}
```

Sometimes the message you get by the debugger is not clear.

Comment: Using quotes around the url name passed to the url tag is correct (and now required unless you want the argument to be interpreted as a variable).

Comment: It is django-userna module,I just not change it,and I don't think it have something wrong with it.